# What happens to the old string object in java while modifying the current object

Tags: java

I got a doubt while trying with the `string` class.
I came to know that string is immutable in java and even if we are performing any string operation to the current string, it will create a new string object. For example, if I apply `trim()` to the current string object then it will create new object. So my question is then what happens to the old string object. Whether it is removed from the heap replacing with the new object or in the other case it will keep on creating string garbage if I am performing a lot of string functions. Please clarify me?

Comment: Obivously nothing happens to it. You could even easily test that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a misconception. When you invoke a string operation, what happens is that you get a new string with the results of that operation. Nothing happens to the old string.

For example

```
String strWithSpaces = "   Dog   ";
String strWithoutSpaces = strWithSpaces.trim();
```

Now you have *two* separate strings. One that has spaces before and after the word "Dog", and one that doesn't.

You may ask what happens if I do

```
String strWithSpaces = "   Dog   ";
strWithSpaces.trim();
```

Well, besically, that creates a new string without the spaces before and after "Dog", but that new string is not assigned to anything, so it is immediately eligible for garbage collection, and **the old string, with the spaces, stays the same as it was**.

And if I do

```
String strWithSpaces = "   Dog   ";
strWithSpaces = strWithSpaces.trim();
```

Again, there are two strings. But now, the new string is assigned to the same variable as the old one. So you have a reference to the new, and you can use it, but you don't have a direct reference to the old. If it wasn't created from a literal string, it would be garbage-collected.

Answer (score 2):

> Whether it is removed from the heap replacing with the new object or in the other case it will keep on creating string garbage if I am performing a lot of string functions.

No object is ever "replacing" another object on the heap. They all get created in a new location. Anyone who happens to still reference the "old" object can continue to use it.

So, yes, you will be producing "string garbage". But you have the garbage collector to take care of that: It removes unused objects in the background (reclaiming their memory to be re-used by future objects). If you happen to do a lot of string operations in a tight loop, consider using a `StringBuilder` or a `char[]` instead. Those exist precisely to avoid the overhead of creating lots of intermediate objects.